# How to record a long video using AVFoundation (>1 min)?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

When I record video using the following view controller:

```
class AVCameraViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    initializeMotionManager()
    sessionQueue.async {
        let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        if self.session.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput) {
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            self.session.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
            self.session.sessionPreset = .high
            if let connection = movieFileOutput.connection(with: .video) {
                if connection.isVideoStabilizationSupported {
                    connection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .auto
                }
            }
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
            movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: 120, preferredTimescale: 60)

            self.movieFileOutput = movieFileOutput

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.recordButton.isEnabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput,
                didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL,
                from connections: [AVCaptureConnection],
                error: Error?) {
    // Note: Since we use a unique file path for each recording, a new recording won't overwrite a recording mid-

save.
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        func cleanup() {
            let path = outputFileURL.path
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: path)
                } catch {
                    print("Could not remove file at url: \(outputFileURL)")
                }
            }

            if let currentBackgroundRecordingID = backgroundRecordingID {
                backgroundRecordingID = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid

                if currentBackgroundRecordingID != UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid {
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(currentBackgroundRecordingID)
                }
            }
        }

        var success = true

        if error != nil {
            print("Movie file finishing error: \(String(describing: error))")
            success = (((error! as NSError).userInfo[AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey] as AnyObject).boolValue)!
        }

        if success {
            // Check authorization status.
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){
                self.overlay.alpha = 0.9
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            }
            footageURL = outputFileURL
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "TrimFootage", sender: nil)
        } else {
            cleanup()
        }

        // Enable the Camera and Record buttons to let the user switch camera and start another recording.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Only enable the ability to change camera if the device has more than one camera.
            self.recordButton.isEnabled = true
//            self.recordButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CaptureVideo"), for: [])
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am setting the maxRecordedDuration to 2 minutes. When its done recording successfully, it eventually segues to another view controller.

The problem is right now it only records for a minute and then stops recording and segues. Im not sure if Im not setting the maxRecordedDuration correctly or if I have to be doing something else instead.

Comment: Hey, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902410/trying-to-understand-cmtime/13001917#13001917) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake) post helps.

Comment: @LoVo I started using CMTime(seconds: 120, preferredTimescale: 1) which according to those posts is 120 seconds. The behavior of my camera hasn't changed - it still stops at 1 minute. Thus Im not sure if its an issue with the CMTime itself but rather the way I assign it to the camera?

Comment: I suspect background task may kill it after 1 min. First try if it works foreground.

Answer (score 1):

I just used this code: (Most of it comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697568/capturing-video-with-avfoundation) accepted answer. Thanks @gwinyai. You should upvote his answer. I already did. ;)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var camPreview: UIView!

    let cameraButton = UIView()

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    var activeInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

    var outputURL: URL!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        movieOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: 120, preferredTimescale: 600)
        if setupSession() {
            setupPreview()
            startSession()
        }

        cameraButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let cameraButtonRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.startCapture))

        cameraButton.addGestureRecognizer(cameraButtonRecognizer)

        cameraButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

        cameraButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        camPreview.addSubview(cameraButton)

    }

    func setupPreview() {
        // Configure previewLayer
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = camPreview.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        camPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    }

    //MARK:- Setup Camera

    func setupSession() -> Bool {

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

        // Setup Camera
        let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)!

        do {

            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
                activeInput = input
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error setting device video input: \(error)")
            return false
        }

        // Setup Microphone
        let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)!

        do {
            let micInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(micInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(micInput)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error setting device audio input: \(error)")
            return false
        }


        // Movie output
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
        }

        return true
    }

    func setupCaptureMode(_ mode: Int) {
        // Video Mode

    }

    //MARK:- Camera Session
    func startSession() {

        if !captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func stopSession() {
        if captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.stopRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func videoQueue() -> DispatchQueue {
        return DispatchQueue.main
    }

    func currentVideoOrientation() -> AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
        var orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation

        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .portrait:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        case .landscapeRight:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown
        default:
            orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
        }

        return orientation
    }

    @objc func startCapture() {
        if movieOutput.isRecording == false {
            startRecording()
            print("-------- startRecording --------")
        } else {
            stopRecording()
            print("-------- stopRecording --------")

        }
    }

    func tempURL() -> URL? {
        let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString

        if directory != "" {
            let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
            return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        }

        return nil
    }


    func startRecording() {

        if movieOutput.isRecording == false {
            let connection = movieOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)

            if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
                connection?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
            }

            if (connection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
                connection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
            }

            let device = activeInput.device

            if (device.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported) {

                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    device.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print("Error setting configuration: \(error)")
                }

            }
            outputURL = tempURL()
            movieOutput.startRecording(to: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)
        }
        else {
            stopRecording()
        }

    }

    func stopRecording() {
        if movieOutput.isRecording == true {
            movieOutput.stopRecording()
        }
    }

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

        if let error = error,
            let nserror = error as NSError? {
            switch nserror.code {
            case AVError.Code.maximumDurationReached.rawValue:
                //no error because we want to stop if max duration is reached
                print(output.maxRecordedDuration.seconds, "<<<<<<<<<<<<" )
                recordingEnded()
                return

            default:
                //handle error
                print(nserror.userInfo)
                break
            }
        } else {
            //user manually stopped the video before maxduration was reached
             recordingEnded()
        }
    }

    func recordingEnded() -> Void {
        print("recording ended successfully")
        let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL
    }
}
```

to stop recording after 120 seconds.

It works! You just need to add the `camPreview` in Storyboard and make sure you have `Privacy - Microphone Usage Description` and `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` added to your `.plist`.

Why `movieOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: 120, preferredTimescale: 600)`

> Apple recommends a timescale of 600 for video, with the explanation
>   that 600 is a multiple of the common video framerates (24, 25, and 30
>   FPS). You might want to crank this up to 60,000 or higher if you need
>   sample-exact indexing on audio files. ....

Check [here](https://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming self.session refers to an instance of AVCaptureSession. Try moving the `maxRecordedDefinition` property definition right after the definition of `movieFileOutput`

```
let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTime(seconds: 120, preferredTimescale: 1)
```

You may be prematurely committing the session configuration with incorrect settings.

(Also, use a preferredTimescale of 1, representing one whole second - but I think you already noted that in a comment above.)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot sort it out by maxRecordedDuration, may I suggest to try and remove that and set a timer instead. It would trigger when recording starts and run for 120 secs. If you press stop before, just invalidate it so it doesn't trigger. If timer runs to end, just call stopRecording function that will stop recording and trigger segue you want.

Would that work out?

```
private var timer: Timer?

private func startRecording() {
    // Code to start recording, you can start timer here once you start recording
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 120, repeats: false, block: { [weak self] (t) in
        guard let welf = self else {return}
        welf.stopRecording()
    })
}
private func stopRecording() {
    // Code to stop recording and segue further
}
```

Comment: Or you use `UIImagePickerController` and the property `videoMaximumDuration`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619146-videomaximumduration)